# How to get sys.databases or sys.tables from sql in ef core

Tags: sql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a question what I couldn't resolve it for 2 days. I'm working on .NET Core 2.2 by the way and thats why I'm using Entity Framework Core.

I need to get sys.databases, sys.tables and sys.columns from sql but I couldn't reach them whatever I tried.

Someone advised me; Create a Stored Procedure and get them this way.

```
var result = dbcontext.Databases.FromSql("sp_GetDatabases").ToList();
```

- I've tried but didn't reach because I don't want specific data in context. 
  This only applies to data in DbContext.

So I didn't find how to get them. Need some help!

Comment: For a more detailed answer w/ a stored proc, see Ritesh's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120207/executing-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-core-2-0 . In EF Core 3.1+ `FromSql` has been replaced with `FromSqlRaw`

Answer (score 2):

```
var connectionDb = _context.Database.GetDbConnection();
if (connectionDb.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed))
    connectionDb.Open();
object data = null;
using (var command = connectionDb.CreateCommand())
{
command.CommandText = @"Your query here";

data = command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Bit too late. But might help someone else out.